# Checkout with auto merge

Tags: git, git-checkout

Sometimes when I use `git checkout master` the changes made in my previous branch are automatically merged into master:

```
cat >> some_file.txt
change from branch1
git checkout master
```

This outputs that the changes made to `some_file.txt` are merged into `master`. For example:

```
M some_file.txt
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
```

Why do I get a merge without explicitly telling git to do so? (Im using git from brew on OSX).

Comment: If you don't want an automatic merge, do fetch instead.  git pull does a fetch followed by a merge .

Answer (score 0):

The checkout did not merge the file, git is just telling you that after the checkout  `some_file.txt` is still modified from before tour checkout. That's what the M means not merge. As of now it is not merges nor added for commit.

If you don't want that version of `some_file.txt` you can always do `git checkout master some_file.txt` which should give you the `some_file.txt` that is currently on your master.